# Could not find records in nighter success nor error folder in informatica

Tags: database, unix, informatica-powercenter

Can some one help me to resolve the below Issue

We are working for migration project, as migrating from windows to Unix. In  Dev environment there is a code which was already developed by someone.we made some changes as per the Unix.

Ran the workflow in Unix Dev environment, records are loaded in error folder.

The same code has been migrated to Unix test environment. However same I have tested in test environment(unix) with same file. Records(6 records)  suppose to go to error folder in Unix just like in windows Environment.

Records (total 6 records) are reading from source in test env. but not loading(6 records)  in error file as well as success file. Total '0' records showing. Connections and paths all are correct.

Please help me to get this fix.

Comment: If you want help you must share information so we can apply our minds. Logfiles from the session ran on windows and unix would be a start. A list of the properties and config tab settings for the affected session and the settings for the affected targets on the mappings tab for the session

Comment: Thank you...Daniel and can I have your Email link so that I can share it over there.

Comment: Sorry but I only correspond via the forum